# How to check a regular expression is valid without using it for a search?

Tags: regular-expressions

I would like to write a package that uses user defined regular expressions.

Is there a way to validate a regular expression is valid without having to perform a search, showing a helpful message when it's not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check it interactively:

```lisp
(defcustom foo "" "foo" :type 'regexp :group 'emacs)
```

Try giving it an invalid regexp and setting it, and it will raise an error.

---

Or if you want to test it programmatically, this predicate returns `t` for valid and `nil` for invalid, and when invalid it shows a message with the error type.

```lisp
(defun regexp-valid-p (string)
  "Return nil if STRING is not a valid regexp."
  (condition-case err
      (prog1 t (string-match-p string ""))
    (error (message (error-message-string err))
           nil)))
```

This works because `string-match-p` and `string-match` return either `nil` or non-`nil` for any valid regexp, and they raise an error for an invalid regexp. The `condition-case` just captures the error, converts its message to an ordinary  `message` instead, and returns `nil` for invalid and `t` for valid.

This solution comes almost directly from the definition of function `widget-regexp-match` (or function `widget-regexp-validate`) in standard library `wid-edit.el`.

In other words, I started from knowing that Customize checks validity of a field of `:type regexp`, and looked for the code that checked that.

---

Another programmatic solution, also found by looking in the Elisp source code:
use function `mh-index-parse-search-regexp`, defined in standard library `mh-search.el`.

Example:

```lisp
(mh-index-parse-search-regexp "\\(ab") ;; Raises an invalid-regexp error.
```

That function depends on these functions being defined:

- `mh-replace-string`         ; Defined in `mh-utils.el`.
- `mh-index-add-implicit-ops` ; Defined in `mh-search.el`.
- `mh-index-evaluate`         ; Defined in `mh-search.el`.

---

**Moral:** If what you want to do seems like something that would be useful generally, there's a good chance it's already been done, and a good place to start looking is the source Lisp code provided with Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

You can test a regular expression on a document with `M-x re-builder` and build it interactively. Faulty parts are highlighted.